# Can I create a Cognito-compatible JWT that doesn't reference a specific user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, authentication, amazon-cognito

We have a set of APIs in AWS secured by Cognito JWTs.  Authentication of users based on their Cognito IdTokens and authorisation based on Cognito custom properties works great.

Some of our API endpoints are also called by 'service' processes: scheduled processes or maintenance tasks which are run from Lambda functions and are not associated with any 'real' user.  We need these processes to be able to generate some sort of authentication/authorisation token which can be validated by the API.

I've considered :

1. **Creating a real 'admin@example.com' Cognito user, storing the password in Secrets Manager, and authenticating as that user in the service functions**.  Not ideal IMO because it requires managing the existence of a data object as part of the infrastructure, and might also be an availability pinch point.
2. **Generating a different secret token for the service functions, and special-case its validation in the APIs**.  Not ideal because now we have to manually maintain compatibility to the Cognito JWT signature, plus it's reinventing a security wheel.  Also, we either have to share a secret between the service functions and the APIs, or manage an RSA keypair.

What I'd really like to do is have some way for service functions to sign a JWT based on their own IAM credentials, which can be validated in the API by a call to STS.  But I *don't* want to pass a 'real' set of STS credentials from the service function (which has permissions to do other things beyond just invoke the API).

In short: *how can I best 'mix' validating Cognito users and Lambda functions in the same API?*